Show that tangent spaces of surface are parallel to the z-axis
I've been reviewing some past exam questions for my intro to differential geometry course and I'd like your opinions on this one:
Show that $x^2+y^2-z^2=1$ defines a regular surface S. After that, show that the tangent spaces at all points $(x,y,0)$ of S are parallel to the z-axis.
I can show the surface is regular no problem but I'm not sure whether my approach to the second question is correct.
I'm thinking of using the $\nabla(f)$ of points of the form $(x,y,0)$ which would give us $\nabla(f)=(2x,2y,0)$. Now we can see that all the vectors generated that way belong on the x-y plane and since the tangent space of a surface at any given point is perpendicular to the $\nabla(f)$ at that same point, it follows that all tangent spaces would be perpendicular to the x-y plane and thus parallel to the z-axis.
Is my approach correct or am I making some horrible mistake?
Thank you all in advance

yes it is correct
